# How does AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP work in django?

Tags: python, django, ldap

I am using following block of code , I copied from web :

```
AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = "cn=GALAXY_login,ou=AppRoles,ou=GALAXY_TEAM,ou=Applications,o=IAM"

AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active":"cn=GALAXY_login,ou=AppRoles,ou=GALAXY_TEAM,ou=Applications,o=IAM",

"is_staff": "cn=GALAXY_login,ou=AppRoles,ou=GALAXY_TEAM,ou=Applications,o=IAM",

"is_superuser":"cn=GALAXY_superuser,ou=AppRoles,ou=GALAXY_TEAM,ou=Applications,o=IAM"
}
```

If i am only allowing `GALAXY_login` to login into application how will

```
"is_superuser":"cn=GALAXY_superuser,ou=AppRoles,ou=GALAXY_TEAM,ou=Applications,o=IAM"
```

ever return `true`?

My understanding is , I am only permitting the user which is in group `GALAXY_login.` Then how will `"is_superuser"` be true for any user?

Answer (score 0):

You need to authorize members of the *GALAXY_superuser* group role too. You can use an [LDAPGroupQuery](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#django_auth_ldap.config.LDAPGroupQuery) to allow more groups to log in.

See [Limiting Access](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/groups.html#limiting-access) :

> `AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP` and `AUTH_LDAP_DENY_GROUP` alone may not be
>   enough to satisfy your needs. In such cases, you can use the
>   LDAPGroupQuery object to perform more complex matches against a user’s
>   groups.

For example :

```
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPGroupQuery

AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = (
    LDAPGroupQuery("cn=GALAXY_login,ou=AppRoles,ou=GALAXY_TEAM,ou=Applications,o=IAM") | 
    LDAPGroupQuery("cn=GALAXY_superuser,ou=AppRoles,ou=GALAXY_TEAM,ou=Applications,o=IAM")
)
```